# What is the correct way to use CefCookieManager? (VC++)

Tags: chromium-embedded

Greeting,everybody.

I'm  try to make a program which embed a CEF(Chromium embed framework) for html display.

I just want to every browser window created in my program has different CefCookieManager. I had read the documents of CEF and know it's possible.

The code is simple:
First I write a class which inherited from CefRequestContextHandler

```
#pragma once
#include "include/cef_request_context_handler.h"
#include "include/cef_cookie.h"
class WXRequestContextHandler :public CefRequestContextHandler
{
public:
    WXRequestContextHandler(){}
    ~WXRequestContextHandler(){};
    CefRefPtr<CefCookieManager> GetCookieManager() OVERRIDE {
        return CefCookieManager::CreateManager("F:\\", false);
        //return NULL;
         }
private:
    // Include the default reference counting implementation.
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(WXRequestContextHandler);
};
```

then I Create a instance of CefRequestContext:

```
m_reqContext = CefRequestContext::CreateContext(new WXRequestContextHandler());
```

Finally create browser through CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser with the CefRequestContext instance created before:

```
CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(info, m_cefHandler.get(), pszURL, settings, m_reqContext);
```

OK,I think it really easy and in fact I don't know other more about yet,so when I run these code to create the first window I got a exception(triggered in libcef.dll,Access violation 0xc00000005) and program crashed.

Unfortunately,I found the documents and tutorials about  CefCookieManager and CefRequestHandler really poor,so had to found help here.If anybody know some issues about my question or some tutorials about CefCookieManager and CefRequestConextHandler,please help.

I use CEF3.1750(june 2014), VS2013(vc12), win7.

Answer (score 1):

I had solved this problem by myself(through CEF forum):

[here is the link:](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12534)